C code reading only part of a matrix correctly
While trying to read the following matrix from a .dad file
 1  3 −3  1
−1  3  2  0
 2  4  0  7

the program bizarrely only reads the first two values:
PS C:\Users\...\P1> gcc -o main_gauss main_gauss.c linalg.c  
PS C:\Users\...\P1> ./main_gauss.exe

Matrix A:
1.000000 3.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000

It does so consistently i.e. it reads only the first two values irregardless of the matrix. In case it is relevant, I'm using Visual Studio Code.

main_gauss.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linalg.h"

int main(void){
    int n = 3;
    int m = 4;

    /* Allocate memory for matrix A */
    double **A = (double **) malloc(n * sizeof(double *));  // Allocate memory for rows
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        A[i] = (double *) malloc(m * sizeof(double));       // Allocate memory for columns
    }

    read_matrix(n, m, A, "Gauss1.dad");

    return 0;
}

linalg.c:
#include "linalg.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void read_matrix(int n, int m, double **A, char *s){
    /* Open the file */
    FILE * file ;
    file = fopen (s, "r");
    if ( file == NULL ){
        printf("Error opening %s\n", ".dad file."); 
        return;
    }

    /* Import data to A */
    printf("\nMatrix A:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            fscanf(file, "%lf", &A[i][j]);      
            printf("%lf ", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf ("\n");
    fclose(file);   // Close the file
}

lingalg.h:
#ifndef LINALG_H
#define LINALG_H

void read_matrix(int n, int m, double **A, char *s);

#endif


If you haven't done it before, now seems like the perfect time to learn how to debug your programs. Like for example use a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values.

On a different note, always check what fscanf (or any other function in the scanf family) returns.

As my answer explains, you have incorrect characters in your data file. In the future, you should reduce a question like this to an [mre]. For this problem, you should have identified that an fscanf call was failing, and then you should have edited the data file to have only the specific item was failing and edited the program to consist only of a main routine and an fopen and a single fscanf that demonstrated the problem. All loops and memory allocation and other unnecessary code should have been removed. Doing basic debugging and these steps would have directed you to the problem.

Also, in C you should not cast the result of malloc, or any other function returning void *.

@EricPostpischil will keep it in mind :). I did remove most of the code (it's a Gaussian elimination assingment), but left the loops as I thought the problem could reside in how I was looping through the data.

You have minus signs in the data, Unicode character 8722. The %lf conversion of fscanf expects a hyphen to represent a minus sign. Edit the Gauss1.dad file to change the minus signs to hyphens. Or edit the code to read the characters (as strings or individual characters, not with %lf) and parse the minus signs.
